# Firebird 3.0 and perl DBD::Firebird

Tags: 18.04

I tried to connect to my firebird 3.0 server on ubuntu 18.04 from a perl script.

I could not install "cpan -f -i DBD::Firebird", header files were not found.

Does anyone know were to find "ibase.h"?

Answer (score 1):

After investigating a while I found that include files are missing and have to be installed from firebird source.

Download the firebird 3.0 source from https://firebirdsql.org/ and copy all files from /opt/firebird/include to /usr/include

You should also create a new symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.3.0.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so
```